# Regex - match everything but forward slash

Tags: regex

in the following string:

/seattle/restaurant

I would like to match Seattle (if it is present) (sometimes the url might be /seattle/restaurant and sometimes it might be /restaurant). What I don't want is to match the following forward slash: seattle/

I have tried the following, but I cannot get it to work:

```
       /(.*[^/]?)restaurant(\?.*)?$
```

I need the first forward slash, so the solution is not to remove that, which I can do like this:

```
     (/?)(.*)/restaurant(\?.*)?$
```

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
^/([^/]+)/?(.*)$
```

I tested it with python and seems to work fine:

```
>>> regex=re.compile(r'^/([^/]+)/?(.*)$')
>>> regex.match('/seattle').groups()
('seattle', '')
>>> regex.match('/seattle/restaurant').groups()
('seattle', 'restaurant')
```

Comment: I think `'/seattle/restaurant'.split('/')` would do the same thing.