# Matching certain path pattern and excluding other forward slashes

Tags: php, regex

I am new to Regex.
I want to match a certain URL pagePath pattern for Analytics.

**The Problem:**

The pattern looks like this:

```
/(de|en|fr|it)/../any-word-including-dashes/word-or-words-including-dashes-and-numbers
```

I want to match only this pattern and exclude all pagePathes with another forward slash or not matching the initial pattern:

Include:

```
/de/ab/word-word/word1-and-something-else
/de/ab/word-word/word1-and-something-else?any_ting1=any.-thing2
```

Exclude:

```
/de/ab/word-word/word1-and-something-else/
/de/ab/word-word/word1-and-something-else/anything
/de/ab/word-word
/fr/moreThanTwoCHAR/anything
```

**My Regex:**

After having searched on SO ([Exclude forward slash before end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273135/regex-match-everything-but-forward-slash) , ["Match anything but"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but?rq=1) and [Finding exactly n occurences of "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518092/regex-to-find-at-least-4-occurrences-of-forward-slash-in-string), [disallow 0 or more occurences of a CHAR](https://superuser.com/questions/281603/match-all-strings-containing-only-one-character)) I came up with the following regex:

> ```
> ^(\/de|\/fr|\/en|\/it)\/..\/.+\/\w+[^\/]*
> ```

*What it does correctly*

It excludes correctly the following path:

```
/fr/moreThanTwoCHAR/anything
```

*What it fails on*

The problem with the above regex is that it matches also (tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)):

```
/de/ab/word-word/word1-and-something-else/anything
```

And I can't seem to understand why it matches the string with an additional forward slash even if I stated to exclude 0 or more additional occurences (at least from what I understood). Anyone can explain me where I'm mistaken?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew , I see what my fault was (having used the `[^\/]` wrongly).
Would you want to answer my question so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.` matches any char (except line break chars if no DOTALL option (`/s`) is used) thus your regex just matches more types of input than you need.

You may use

```
'~^/(de|fr|en|it)/[^/]{2}(?:/[^/]+){2}$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4u3Gyh/2).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of input
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(de|fr|en|it)` - one of the three alternative substrings: `de`, `fr`, `en` or `it`
- `/[^/]{2}` - `/` and then any 2 chars other than `/`
- `(?:/[^/]+){2}` - 2 consecutive sequences of a `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of input.